# Error registering ApplicationInsights WebRequestTrackingModuleRegister when publishing to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying to publish a web app into Azure. It publishes successfully but I get a runtime error when hitting a page.

Here is the stack trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: moduleType]
   System.Web.DynamicModuleRegistry.Add(Type moduleType) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterModule(Type moduleType) +65
   Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(Type moduleType) +36
   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AzureWebSites.WebRequestTrackingModuleRegister.Register() +38

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Register on type Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AzureWebSites.WebRequestTrackingModuleRegister threw an exception with the following error message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: moduleType.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +586
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +129
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +163
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +156
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +621

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Register on type Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AzureWebSites.WebRequestTrackingModuleRegister threw an exception with the following error message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: moduleType.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +660
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +96
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
```

I'm not sure what the reason is for this. I simply added the nuget package for App Insights for Web Applications and then updated the InstrumentationKey in the AppInsights.config file included in the project. These are the same steps I have used before to get it working but this time it produces this strange result!

Anybody ran into this before?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when setting up a second site for AppInsights on Azure.  The first site was setup a few months ago using version 0.16.1-build00418 (prerelease) and everything worked fine.  Just today I setup a second Azure site using version 1.1.0 and ran into the same error you got.

While I don't know the exact cause I was able to solve the issue by completely deleting the content of the site and then re-publishing.

The only way I know how to fully delete the site content is by FTPing to the site. You can get the FTP connection information by downloading the publish profile for the site from the Azure portal.  Then delete everything under /site/wwwroot and re-publish.